# `SequencePosition` doing unnecessary work

Tags: pattern-matching, built-in-symbols, computational-complexity

`SequencePosition` returns only the first sequence in a list that matches a given pattern with

```
SequencePosition[list,pattern,1]
```

But it looks like it still pattern-matches the entire list anyway! This code gives it a trivial example which should be constant time but in fact exhibits exponential time complexity:

```
trailingCharacters[n_] := 
  trailingCharacters[n] = 
   Characters["abcdefg"]~Join~
    RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], Floor[10^n]];

Table[trailingCharacters[n], {n, 1, 8, 0.25}];

ListLogPlot[Table[
  Timing[
    SequencePosition[
        trailingCharacters[n],
        Characters["abcdefg"],
        1
     ]
    ][[1]],
  {n, 1, 8, 0.25}
  ]]
```

Is this a bug? If it's not a bug, is there a slick way to tell Mathematica to stop pattern-matching after finding the first sequence?

Comment: You are timing not only execution of `SequencePosition` but also creation of the list by `trailingCharacters` and also joining it with another list in `Characters["abcdefg"]~Join~` so your code has no relevance in judging performance of `SequencePosition`. First create all the joined lists and then time only execution of `SequencePosition` on those lists.

Comment: @azerbajdzan you are correct about the `Join` operation but not about the creation of `trailingCharacters`, which is memoized. I'll change the post but it doesn't have a qualitative effect.

Comment: So once you removed `Join` from `Timing` all timings are zero, i.e. all equally fast executed by `SequencePosition`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No exponential increase of time can be seen bellow:

```
data = Table[
   Characters["abcdefg"]~Join~
    RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], Floor[10^n]], {n, 1, 8, 
    0.25}];
AbsoluteTiming[SequencePosition[#, Characters["abcdefg"], 1]] & /@ data
Clear[data]

(* {{0.000144, {{1, 7}}}, {0.0000632, {{1, 7}}}, {0.0000572, {{1, 
    7}}}, {0.0000536, {{1, 7}}}, {0.0000528, {{1, 
    7}}}, {0.0000481, {{1, 7}}}, {0.000052, {{1, 
    7}}}, {0.0000497, {{1, 7}}}, {0.000053, {{1, 
    7}}}, {0.0000505, {{1, 7}}}, {0.0000498, {{1, 
    7}}}, {0.0000514, {{1, 7}}}, {0.0000564, {{1, 
    7}}}, {0.000051, {{1, 7}}}, {0.0000474, {{1, 
    7}}}, {0.0000502, {{1, 7}}}, {0.0000491, {{1, 
    7}}}, {0.0000503, {{1, 7}}}, {0.0000569, {{1, 
    7}}}, {0.0000503, {{1, 7}}}, {0.000063, {{1, 
    7}}}, {0.0000502, {{1, 7}}}, {0.0000459, {{1, 
    7}}}, {0.0000501, {{1, 7}}}, {0.0000474, {{1, 
    7}}}, {0.0000485, {{1, 7}}}, {0.0000466, {{1, 
    7}}}, {0.0000481, {{1, 7}}}, {0.0000459, {{1, 7}}}} *)
```

On the other hand if we use OP code we can see that first time table of `trailingCharacters` is executed it takes some increasing time. On the second execution of the same table we have all zeros times because the result was memorized from first run.

But then if we execute `Timing[Identity[trailingCharacters[8]]][[1]]` twice in a row we again have big time for the first run and zero for the second run even though no `SequencePosition` was used but just `Identity`.

Why it happens? I think maybe because of using memory caching because `trailingCharacters[8]` is quite large about 4GB.

```
trailingCharacters[n_] := 
  trailingCharacters[n] = 
   Characters["abcdefg"]~Join~
    RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], Floor[10^n]];

Table[Timing[trailingCharacters[n]][[1]], {n, 1, 8, 0.25}]
Table[Timing[trailingCharacters[n]][[1]], {n, 1, 8, 0.25}]

Timing[Identity[trailingCharacters[8]]][[1]]
Timing[Identity[trailingCharacters[8]]][[1]]

Out[3]= {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., \
0., 0., 0., 0.015625, 0., 0.03125, 0.03125, 0.046875, 0.09375, \
0.15625, 0.265625, 0.484375, 0.78125, 1.53125}

Out[4]= {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., \
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}

Out[5]= 1.53125

Out[6]= 0.
```